# Get all data displayed in DOM javascript from object

Tags: javascript, firebase, dom, firebase-realtime-database

I have made a firebase database with products. The GET works, the data shows in console, the data displays first product with picture but the rest without. The first product dont have any buy button but the rest of the products have.

```
async function getProducts(){
  try{
    const baseURL = 'https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
    const url = baseURL + 'Products.json'
    const response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)

    const generatedHTML = Object.keys(data).reduce((accum, currKey) => accum +
    
    
    `
      <div>${data[currKey].namn}</div>
      <div class="image"><img class="skor-img" src="${data[currKey].img}" alt=""></div>
      <div class="beskrivning"><strong class="text">Description</strong><br><br><p        class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p></div>
      <div class="pris"><p>lager: ${data[currKey].lager}</p> <button class="euro">Buy:${data[currKey].pris}kr</button></div>`
    , '')
      
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =generatedHTML 
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  
}

getProducts()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxTsD.png)

I have used a forEach loop but then only product id shows. How can I display all information from the database out in the DOM in javascript? Im using object.keys and reduce.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why use `Object.keys()` instead of `Object.values()`? You never use `currKey` except to index into `data`.

Comment: Do you see all the images if you check the DOM inspector?

Comment: This sounds like it may be a CSS problem.

Comment: @barmar it seems they all lays under the first picture above eachother

Comment: That definitely sounds like a CSS problem. Try wrapping each item in a container DIV.

Comment: if I do it directly from index.html then it shows with CSS as it should. But from javascript to DOM its not the same style.

Comment: okey ill try with wrapping!

Comment: yes thank you that worked! now I just need to style it a bit better.